# How to stop fiddler to decrypting our https traffic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, nginx, https, fiddler

We have used https for our ruby on rails based application.

Once we configure our system/laptop with fiddler then we are able to see our traffic in fiddler (like our username or password .. everything).

Is there anyway to stop fiddler to decrypting our https based request ?

Comment: Yes, remove fiddler's certificate from the browser/system list of trusted certs.

Comment: Or simply uncheck "Decrypt HTTPS Traffic" in fiddler settings.

Comment: https://www.fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, i mean to say that if someone else has installed the fiddler certificate and user didn't notice while connecting our application, so fiddler will be able to get his/her username/password/sensitive data.  I am looking for any solution to stop fiddler or any such kind of software to tracking our https traffic.

Comment: No, that's not possible. As they say in information security: "if someone has physical access to your computer, it's not your computer anymore". Same for ability to install/configure software remotely. It's not your computer, it's attacker's computer.

Comment: It is actually possible to some extent. Look into Public Key Pinning - if the web app sends the publickeypins header, the victims browser will remember the public key and if Fiddler is inbetween, it will fail to load for the victim, making traffic sniffing less useful. There are limitations though.

Comment: @GaborLengyel: not sure if this can protect against a malicious actor who _can install software on target's machine_.

Comment: While checking with some other banking site, we have seen that the password won't be visible for  banking site but in our ruby on rails application, we are able to see.